# Audit Records Written to BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT

Tags: spring-batch

I have a spring batch application that reads from DB and writes to a topic. Simple enough and works. I am currently writing out each record to a log4j file, but after thinking further, It would be nice if the recordID would be written out to one fo the BATCH_* tables for auditing. I am performing chunk reads/writes and I am not sure to get the data into a step context (I think) so it is written to the BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT short_context column. Or if there is a better way to audit using batch_tables.

Thanks,

Comment: I don't think the context tables are appropriate for this data.  Are you unable to create your own audit table that you could write to in a ChunkListener.afterChunk method?

Edit: You could also use a CompositeItemWriter

Comment: Yes, I think that is a better approach. Thanks Joe.